# GraphQL Dynamic schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

Relatively new in the GraphQL domain, I'm currently trying to transform an existing REST API into a GraphQL one. Coming from the REST system, I keep trying to follow the different philosophies about GraphQL in order to well understand the different concepts. That's on this point I would have some questions if you please.

Concerning my project, for now, the REST API has been designed to be fully dynamic (using MongoDB and Symfony). We were using the `ReflectionClass` to make everything similar and to avoid code duplication in controllers for example. Concerning the new API, it would run on the nodeJS environment.

So, my question is: do you think it is possible to imagine a similar logic when you design a GRAPHQL API?

After some researches, if I well understand, it seems this system to be very attached to the static schema concept (.gql files) and let's end user to define all the query.
Would a global schema or prototype schema be a good idea? I mean define kind of inheritance or similar.

The point is that during my implementation tests to translate the REST API to a new Graphql one, I had to redefine each model with the mongoose in JS, in Graphql (.gql) and define resolvers related to.
Maybe I miss something or did something wrong but in my resolvers, a lot of fields are copied/pasted (for dbref for example).
Furthermore, when I think about maintenance, what if tomorrow we add a new field? Do we need to explicitly define it in mongoose and Graphql?

Did you face the same issues or found any workaround? I would be glad to talk and share about it!

Thanks

**example of person resolver:**

```
Query: {
    //single person
    async person(obj, args, context, fieldASTs) {
        if (args.id) {
            const projection = mongoose.makeProjections(fieldASTs);

             return await person.findById({
                '_id': ObjectId(args.id)
            }, projection);
         }

        return null;
    },
    // all persons
    async persons(obj, args, context, fieldASTs) {
        const projection = mongoose.makeProjections(fieldASTs);

        return await person.find({}, projection);
   }
},
person: {
    async root(obj, args, context, fieldASTs) {
        if (!obj) {
            return null;
        }

        const projection = mongoose.makeProjections(fieldASTs);

        return await Person.findById({
           '_id': ObjectId(obj.root)
        }, projection);
    }
}
```

**graphql schema**

```
type Person {
  id:            ID
  created:       Date
  root:          Person
  name:          String
}

type Query {
   persons: [Person]
   person(id: ID): Person
}
```

Comment: Would you please share some parts of your code?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my post

Comment: Edited: So the duplicated part of my code in my resolvers is mostly about fields, it's always something like, checking values, calling the mongoose model to find the object by it's ID.

Comment: facebook [dataloader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) is a greate match with graphql, mybe it could save some of your time, anyway I think your code looks good now and these transformations are pretty normal

Comment: @Mosius Thank you for you reply, so if I'm right, I may use dataloader to avoid multiple database calls to get the same object, that's it?

Comment: It is one of it's usages of course